# How to do end task similar to that in Windows?

Tags: freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Sometimes Ubuntu freezes and I have no other option than to power off system directly. Is there some remedy or way like 'Ctrl + Alt + Del' similar to that in Windows. That would be very helpful.....

I need a way out other than option to directly power off my system in times of gross failure. Shutting down this way always creates fear crashing down my system or losing some data which is unacceptable.